# Handling migrations for Multiple DbContexts

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

My scenario is that I have added Identity to an existing .Net Core 6 Blazor Server project. This obviously creates a DbContext that inherits from IdentityDbContext.

However I now need to add my own DbContext for my own entities (not related to Identity but required for the rest of my application). These will exist in the same database as the Identity tables (this is a small project and doesn't need multiple databases). This bit is easy as I obviously just use the same connection string.

My question is, how do I correctly handle migrations for both contexts? I don't want to create a migration for my entities only for that to undo changes in my IdentityDbContext. Ideally I would like to create a single migration that handles updates to database object for BOTH DbContexts at the same time (especially as they exist in the same database). I realise I can (in fact I have to) specify the Context I want to create a migration for, but what effect will this have on those database objects from the other context?

I have seen mention of using Enable-Migration but can't see any useful examples of applying this to multiple contexts....

I feel like I am overcomplicating the migration by trying to simplify the structure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your own entities in the identity context.

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }  //your own entities
    }
```

Comment: I tried this first. This didn't work. I get an unhandled exception back - looks like my entities are being used to extend the Identity setup, rather than as separate to Identity. Additionally I need my DbContext to inherit from DbContext, not IdentityDbContext don't I?

Comment: @SiStone , it works in my project. after addmigration and update database all the identity table and my own table are in the same database.   A context inherit from identityDBcontext will add the identity tables. It doesn't matter your entities is inside.

Comment: "Additionally I need my `DbContext` to inherit from `DbContext`, not `IdentityDbContext` don't I? " @SiStone  No  `IdentityDbContext`  already inherits from `DbContext`. What unhandled exception is returned with this approach?

Comment: Yeah got it to work now thanks. Exception was due to using an untrackable property type.